# AngularJS: Directive binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create a custom email textbox component, which has two fields. To do this I have this template:

```
<div class="custom">
    <div class="username" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <div class="domain">@{{ domainValue }}</div>
</div>
```

So I can invoke a directive that calls that template, like:

```
<div ng-custom-txt></div>
```

From the directive I want to be able to pass different kind of  values ( domains ) from a model called "ng-domaindata", like:

```
<div ng-domaindata="mydomain1.com" ng-custom-txt></div>
```

My question is, how I can bind the directive with the "domain" field that is in the template?

I tried to use this approach but with no success at all:

**Template: customtemplate.html**

```
<div class="custom">
   <div class="username" contenteditable="true"></div>
   <div class="domain">@{{ domainValue }}</div>
</div>
```

**Page**

```
<div ng-domaindata="mydomain1.com" ng-custom-txt></div>
<div ng-domaindata="mydomain2.com" ng-custom-txt></div>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('ngCustomTxt', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^ngModel',
    templateUrl: 'customtemplate.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngDomaindata, function (newValue){
         scope.domainValue = newValue;
     }
    }
  }
});
```

Obviously it won't work since I'm not able to distinguish these two elements, could someone help me out with this?

Comment: Just a quick tip. Avoid to use your own directive with the prefix ng.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a scope for this directive. It seems that directive are getting a shared scope.
Declaring a scope will force the get a new scope instance.

Also, watchers are executed when the instance where created. In your case, it's setting undefined to the scope.domainData value.

Try to check if the newValue is valid, or use $observe function.

```
app.directive('customTxt', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'customtemplate.html',
    scope : {},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.domainValue = attrs.domaindata;
      scope.$watch(attrs.domaindata, function (newValue){
          console.log('This code will execute when the instance where created. Getting a undefined newValue variable: ', newValue);
          // verifying if the value is valid to set to the scope.
          if (newValue != null) {
              scope.domainValue = newValue;  
          }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kYWbngIms7NWmfdXvAb3?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's getting closer, but I try to go to the next level and I feel like this approach won't work.

I explain myself:

The value of the model is dynamic, updated by another controller and saved in the general scope, so I need somehow to bind the value that is in the general scope to this one, which is local.

With this solution I don't have access to the general scope, how could do it then?

Comment: Hum ok, take a look in this plunker and see if helps: http://plnkr.co/edit/eAFdwi4jztR197wo0QdO?p=info

Comment: Thanks a lot Deividi! Now it's getting even closer! What I need exactly is some short of bidirectional binding between the scopes, I just edited your plunker to show you exactly what I need, please have a look: http://plnkr.co/edit/IBpyZbCV7pOB25oZSYD7?p=preview

So, it seems that works but when I want to update one of the domains from the global scope, clicking on "Change value", it doesn't update the local scope. Right?

Comment: Nice, check this plunker now: http://plnkr.co/edit/u0wP8PSqtguPNqp0L9mQ?p=preview 
i change you var from string to object... there are some roles in inheritence from strings to child scopes. I always use object to make it garantee. If works, I'll update the anwser with some better explanation.

Comment: hey Devidi, so sorry it's taken so long to get back to you! Thanks a lot for all your help, you are awesome! About the last solution, looks great and I was really impressed for the use of objects, but unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me. My app loads the directive before the controller, so when that happens the binding doesn't work between the scopes. I edited your last solution in plunkr to give you an idea of what is going on: http://plnkr.co/edit/rSE2KZDLTGU8JBpyk6Xg?p=preview  Thanks again for all your help! I'm learning a lot because of you

Comment: Ok! I take a look and make some modifications. I Use $timeout instead of setTimeout because this function calls internally $scope.$apply(), which will occurs if your controller was created after the directive. (if you don't use $timeout, you will see the changes only when you press the button) Antoher this is that we are watching the domaindata directly from parent scope (controller). Take a look now: http://plnkr.co/edit/HIXIX5lPDFixDW4zKSNN?p=preview

Comment: you can also think to work in a event-based directive, or get the scope from the controller html. like elem('div from controller').scope(); when controller is initiated.